# Android API 10: system.load(library) fails with an unsatisfied link error Other API levels work fine

Tags: android, java-native-interface, loadlibrary

I have the following code in an Android project:

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("FLAC");
        System.load("libLibFlacWrapper.so");
    }
```

This code runs perfectly well on android 21, and a variety of other API levels i've manually tested.  I've also tried loadLibrary for libLibFlacWrapper.so but that doesn't work either.

However when I try and run the project on an API 10 device I get:

```
Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lxappmedia/xvrclientandroid/FLACStreamEncoder;
E/AndroidRuntime(28810):    at xappmedia.xvrclientandroid.XVRRecognizer.<init>(XVRRecognizer.java:118)
E/AndroidRuntime(28810):    at xappmedia.sdk.service.XVRSpeechRecognizerImpl.<init>(XVRSpeechRecognizerImpl.java:24)
E/AndroidRuntime(28810):    at xappmedia.sdk.core.Global.getSpeechRecognizer(Global.java:426)
E/AndroidRuntime(28810):    at xappmedia.sdk.state.AdDirectorContext.initialize(AdDirectorContext.java:133)
E/AndroidRuntime(28810):    at xappmedia.sdk.state.AdDirector.playAdvertisement(AdDirector.java:186)
E/AndroidRuntime(28810):    at xappmedia.sdk.XappAds.playAd(XappAds.java:812)
E/AndroidRuntime(28810):    at xappmedia.sdk.XappAds$19.run(XappAds.java:629)
E/AndroidRuntime(28810):    at xappmedia.sdk.core.Global$1.run(Global.java:260)
E/AndroidRuntime(28810): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load libLibFlacWrapper.so: findLibrary returned null
E/AndroidRuntime(28810):    at xappmedia.xvrclientandroid.FLACStreamEncoder.<clinit>(FLACStreamEncoder.java:33)
```

The FLAC library loads correctly, but no matter what naming I use for libLibFlacWrapper.so i can't get it to load properly on API 10.

I don't see anything documenting different behaviors between API levels on this topic.

Comment: It seems there are some problems in `JNI_Onload` call in library libLibFlacWrapper.so. Could you see the code and check to see if there is exception throw in `JNI_Onload`

Comment: Nah, i resolved this.  It was a naming issue.  It appears based on my experience here that Android became more flexible with .so naming over time.

Answer (score 1):

We have the same problem. It seems that Android 10 only supports “system.loadLibrary()" writing.